# LOTRO resolution and DirectX problems

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Hi I `have problem with my lotro resolution after todays update`. **The HUD is really big but I tried to change it in my userpreferences64.ini folder but it seems it didn't work.** *Second problem is* when **I minimalize my lotro client and try to open it it gives me these errors** : `Could not initialize DirectX. Please ensure that DirectX9.0c[Dec 2005] or higher is installed[105]` `The game encountered a fatal DirectX issue while attemting to start. Try a different screen resolution or bit depth. If that doesn't work, try new video drivers. [128]` Thanks for your answers and advices.

Comment: I don't have that game, but the dx9 error is because when minimizing, the dx9 render context is lost and the game is not able to restore it. You can try "borderless window" mode if available. I *think* you can select e.g. dx 10 or dx11 mode for that game as well, so you might bypass the error entirely if you select a newer dx render option (?)